# Rails : How to query all children of a parent category and then their children and so on using recursion (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I want to query all children of a category to n level

My Category Model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :child_links, class_name: 'CategoryLink', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  has_many :children, through: :child_links
  has_many :parent_links, class_name: 'CategoryLink', foreign_key: 'child_id'
  has_many :parents, through: :parent_links

  def all_children
    all_children = []
    all_children += children
    all_children.each do |child|
      all_children += child.all_children
    end
    all_children
  end
end
```

Intermediary CategoryLink model :

```
class CategoryLink < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :child, class_name: "Category"
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category"
end
```

If I am using @category.all_children, then it builds too much query to database.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you try to adding `includes` call to your queries?

Comment: how to use includes in this scenario ?

Comment: in your each loop `child.includes(:children).all_children` and then try to call `@category.includes(:children).all_children`

Comment: `includes` only helps you to avoid querying once and again the table, but still this could be solved in a different way

Comment: What i am looking is for some recursive query.

Comment: @Mehmet Adil this includes method is throwing error 'undefined method 'includes' for Category

Comment: @Sebastian may I know if any way to solve this?

Comment: I'm going to try something, I just need to take time to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: You can do a recursive query with `.eager_load(children: { children: { children: :children }}})`. This will create a series of "nested" left outer joins and load the associations.

Comment: @max, can u write the complete query / changes required

Comment: Please note There are two tables here. One is 'categories' which stores just name. And another table 'category_links' which holds parent_id and child_id.

Comment: I'm working on an answer. Just got to replicate your setup.

Comment: I asked a similar question not long ago about sorting based on the parent ID. It's by no means the same question but I think a similar kind of approach could be used and it would be a good starting point. Basically the solution was a recursive CTE SQL query. You can use an ActiveRecord `where()` method to pass in part of the query to get the categories you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62677233/order-sql-results-where-each-record-referencing-another-record-on-the-same-table

Comment: When ever things get complicated like this pure SQL is usually the best option.Using Ruby/Rails/ActiveRecord will only complicate things further.

Comment: But the difficulty here, there are two tables involved.